# Not able to find asp.net Tab in IIS 6 Application Pool Properties

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have 2 applications with different .net versions (2 & 4). I have created 2 application pools with different names, I need to set different .net version to each application pool. however I am not able to find asp.net tab in IIS 6 application pool properties window to set different .net version. how to get the tab or how to set different version using command line

FYI

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't set an ASP.NET version for an application pool, you set an ASP.NET version for a website. So under IIS, just go to website ==> Properties ==> ASP.NET tab and set your asp.net version from there.

Comment: There is no asp.net tab in the website properties also

Comment: @Somashekhar When you right click a website in IIS 6 and go to its properties, you should be able to see the following tabs. Website, Performance, ISAPI Filters, Home Directory, Documents, Directory Security, HTTP Headers,Custom Errors and ASP.NET

Comment: There is no tab in both the places i.e application pool &  web site properties window I am 100% sure